# Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments inワードプレスでの不具合。サイトが見れない状態に。

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスでサイトを運営しています。

以下の文が出てサイトが見れない状態です。

```
Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/ログインID？/public_html/サイト名/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2668
```

実際のその部分のコード

```
2667    function zeroise( $number, $threshold ) {
2668        return sprintf( '%0' . $threshold . 's', $number );
2669    }
```

この部分が何か異常があるのでしょうか？

教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 参考 (重複候補): 過去の類似質問です。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68761 , https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53968

Comment: $threshold の中身はなんですか？